# Rescaling pyramid plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

How can I produced a pyramid plot in R with different starting point of the scales other than 0?

I am trying to produce a pyramid plot in R as below using the below code. I want to rescale it such that it does not start from 0 but 0.7 on both halves. can someone help? below is my code and attached is the the resulting plot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpol)

df <- tibble(
Population = c(5, 8.7, 16.7, 24.8, 38, -4.6, -6.4, -16.1, -39.6, -55.3),
Gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
           "Female", "Female", "Female"),
AgeBand = c("65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80-84", "85+", "65-69", "70-74", 
            "75-79", "80-84", "85+")
)
ggplot(df, aes(x = AgeBand, y = Population, fill = Gender)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
facet_share(~Gender, dir = "h", scales = "free", reverse_num = TRUE) +  
# note: scales = "free"
coord_flip() +
theme_minimal() +
labs(y = "Count", x = "Age Band", title = " ") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "blue"))
```

Resulting plots from the codes:
[image: Resulting plots from the codes]

Comment: I get the following error when running your code: `Error in axes$y$left[[1]]$children$axis$grobs[[lab_idx]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses ggplot_build() to allow you to get to the underlying pieces that make up the rendered plot. We can then manually update these, use ggplot_gtable() to restructure the data such that we can use cowplot::plot_grid() to display.  Note I removed the theme as it was leading to an error message.

```
q <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = AgeBand, y = Population, fill = Gender)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   facet_share(~Gender, dir = "h", scales = "free", reverse_num = TRUE) +   # note: scales = "free"
   coord_flip() +
   labs(y = "Count", x = "Age Band", title = " ") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "blue")) 

pq <- ggplot_build(q)

#Update the breaks according to how you want them to display. The first
#set of breaks is what appears first, on the left, and the second is the
#one on right

pq$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$breaks <- c(NA, -40.0, -20.0, -0.7)
pq$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$minor_breaks <- c(-50, -40, -30, -20, -10, NA)
pq$layout$panel_params[[2]]$x$breaks <- c(0.7, 15, 30, NA)
pq$layout$panel_params[[2]]$x$minor_breaks <- c(NA, 10, 20, 30, 40)


qt <- ggplot_gtable(pq)
cowplot::plot_grid(qt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for this. i really do appreciate you.

Comment: I have one more worry. I want either halves to be based on different scales. I want the first halve to be scaled as (0.7-0.9) and the second (0.8-1). This is because the difference in the values of what i am actually working on is  so small and i want the plot to display this difference clearly. Thanks in advance

Comment: These are my value [0.8578, 0.8413, 0.8345, 0.8667] and [0.9034, 0.9848, 0.9874, 0.9884]

Comment: Different scales should work, but those scales don't fit this data set. Just remember the first set of scales should be negatives, and the scales should also be in increasing order. I will update my answer to show separate scales.